# ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding

Tags: python, qt

I want to use `%matplotlib qt` in jupyter notebook. I tried `import PyQt5` and it worked. But when i run `%matplotlib qt` i got this error
`ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding`
Issue is that my system is unable to import following packages.

```
from .backend_qt5 import (
         QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, _BackendQT5, FigureCanvasQT, FigureManagerQT,
        NavigationToolbar2QT, backend_version)
```

I even installed QTCreator.

I am using Ubuntu version 20.04, Python 3.8

Comment: really, i never focus on that, btw its 20.04